# router in Go - run a function before each http request

Tags: go, routes

I'm using Go with http with Go like this:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/API/user", test)
mux.HandleFunc("/authAPI/admin", auth)
```

and I would like to run  a function before every http request
and better yet, run a function on every request that has the /authAPI/ in them.
how can I achieve this in Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On top of what @Thomas has proposed, you can wrap the whole mux in your own mux that is called before any handler is invoked, and can just invoke handlers of its own. That's how alternative http routers are implemented in go. Example:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Handled %s", r.RequestURI)
}


func main(){
    // this will do the actual routing, but it's not mandatory, 
    // we can write a custom router if we want
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/foo", handler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/bar", handler)

    // we pass a custom http handler that does preprocessing and calls mux to call the actual handler
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Preprocessing yo")
        mux.ServeHTTP(w,r)
    }))
}
```

Comment: This is much better, thank you for this alternative. I had no idea muxes were this simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a wrapper function:

```
func wrapHandlerFunc(handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // ...
    // do something
    // ...
    handler(w, req)
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/authAPI/admin", wrapHandlerFunc(auth))
```

Running it automatically for everything under a given URL tree (subrouter, in `mux` parlance) is, as far as I know, not supported.

Comment: thanks, but isn't there any other way? like a global function that would run on all the http handlers?

Comment: Not supported by `mux`, as far as I can see. Edit: also no trace of such functionality in the source code.

Comment: Of course you can do it, just create your own mux that does whatever before passing the work to the real mux.